# iOS 7 storyboard localization with attributed Labels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, localization, storyboard

I am generating my String- Files with ibtool from my Base Storyboard for all my languages...For some reason ibtool is not extracting `UILabel`s with style "attributed"...

I have no Key/Value Pair for those labels...Does somebody has a clue why?!

Comment: Seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459860/localizing-attributed-uitextview-from-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

> I ended up concluding that it couldn't be done using ibtool in the
>   present version.
>
> Instead I let the Textview be a plain text view and, using my
>   subclass, parsed its text property so I could make a
>   NSMutableAttributedString and set the needed properties.
>
> That enabled me to use ibtool to extract the strings and still have an
>   attributed textview.

[Localizing attributed UITextView from storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459860/localizing-attributed-uitextview-from-storyboard)