# Why is UILabel with attributed string from a Storyboard localization not supported?

Tags: ios, localization

I'm puzzled why UILabels using attributed strings are not translated when using the [Storyboard/Xib - strings localization approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22854922). I know I can use code to set it at runtime but I would like to use the default mechanism like for all other controls which don't use attributed strings.

I found questions to my exact same problem like those: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35691380), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22634849), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14459860), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22854922)

But in non of those questions and answer I see no official Apple statement/documentation link why this shouldn't work (Why shouldn't it?).

So, I'm asking why is UILabel with attributed string from a Storyboard localization not supported?

And if there is no hint I would still like to know:

How to localize an UILabel with attributed string from a Storyboard?

**Update**

I also created a [question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661903) in the apple developer forum in the hope to get an official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple [responded on the developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661903) with

> This is not currently supported in Storyboard/XIB. I would encourage you to make a request on [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/).

and ended up using this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35706764), see below. I still hope Apple adds the reason behind this.

```
- (void)localizeAttributedLabel:(UILabel*)label withText:(NSString*)text
{
  NSMutableAttributedString* attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];
  [attributedString.mutableString setString:text];
  label.attributedText = attributedString;
}

[self localizeAttributedLabel:myLabel withText:NSLocalizedString(@"MyLabelTextKey", nil)];
```